# mesos make check failing for http test cases and recieved abort signal for metric test

Tags: makefile, mesos

I have get the mesos source tar ball from here:

```
`wget http://www.apache.org/dist/mesos/0.25.0/mesos-0.25.0.tar.gz`
```

and followed this steps to install dependencies:

```
 # Update the packages.
    $ sudo apt-get update

    # Install the latest OpenJDK.
    $ sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk

    # Install autotools (Only necessary if building from git repository).
    $ sudo apt-get install -y autoconf libtool

    # Install other Mesos dependencies.
    $ sudo apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev python-boto libcurl4-nss-dev libsasl2-dev maven libapr1-dev libsvn-dev
```

Then buid the mesos using following command:

```
# Change working directory.
    $ cd mesos

    # Configure and build.
    $ mkdir build
    $ cd build
    $ ../configure
    $ make
```

and after successful build running the check test cases using:

```
# Run test suite.
    $ make check
```

but the test for HTTPTest.Auth,HTTPTest.Endpoints,HTTPTest.Get,HTTPTest.NestedGet,HTTPTest.StreamingGetComplete,HTTPTest.StreamingGetFailure,HTTPTest.Post,HTTPTest.Delete.
is failing.

Test recieved abort signal with message:

```
../../../3rdparty/libprocess/src/tests/metrics_tests.cpp:186: Failure
Failed to wait 15secs for response
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F1123 13:43:47.889951 37811 future.hpp:1052] Check failed: !isFailed() Future::get() but state == FAILED: Socket error while connecting
```

back trace is :

```
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
*** Aborted at 1448266427 (unix time) try "date -d @1448266427" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @     0x2b1906d9acc9 (unknown)
*** SIGABRT (@0x93b3) received by PID 37811 (TID 0x2b1905d166c0) from PID 37811; stack trace: ***
    @     0x2b1905f15340 (unknown)
    @     0x2b1906d9acc9 (unknown)
    @     0x2b1906d9e0d8 (unknown)
    @           0x77c70d google::logging_fail()
    @           0x77c736 google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @           0x77c682 google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @           0x77c084 google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @           0x77ef98 google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @           0x4a0b50 process::Future<>::get()
    @           0x4d8c4c MetricsTest_Snapshot_Test::TestBody()
    @           0x671604 testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0x66c000 testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0x64d135 testing::Test::Run()
    @           0x64d8b8 testing::TestInfo::Run()
    @           0x64defe testing::TestCase::Run()
    @           0x654646 testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests()
    @           0x6723c3 testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0x66ccd0 testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0x6533e2 testing::UnitTest::Run()
    @           0x4d1993 RUN_ALL_TESTS()
    @           0x4d17ad main
```

**EDIT**: Is it socket creation failing?
what wrong am I doing here while building?

Additional info:
mesos version:mesos-0.25.0

uname -a
Linux xilinx720 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

linux distribution: ubuntu 14.04

Comment: It certainly looks like a network-related connection failure. What is the failing test supposed to be doing?

Comment: i guess it will create a socket and run some tests to bind and listen to that socket. but it gives socket error while connect to created socket. Every test waits for 15 sec. to connect to socket and eventually fails.

Comment: did you got this fixed? I am having same issue here